# How to do increase and decrease button?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf in which there is a button increase and decrease amount of products in basket. And it is not working.

This is my Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/decrease{basketItemIndex}")
public String decreaseAmountOfProductsInBasket(@PathVariable Integer basketItemIndex){
    basketService.decreaseAmount(basketItemIndex);
    return "redirect:/basket/";
}
@GetMapping("/increase{basketItemIndex}")
public String increaseAmountOfProductsInBasket(@PathVariable Integer basketItemIndex){
    basketService.increaseAmount(basketItemIndex);
    return "redirect:/basket/";
}
```

This is my Service:

```
public void decreaseAmount(int basketItemIndex) {
    if (basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).getAmount() == 1)
        basketItems.remove(basketItemIndex);
    else {
        basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).setAmount(-1);
    }
}

public void increaseAmount(int basketItemIndex) {
    basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).setAmount(+1);
}
```

And this is my thymeleaf:

```html
 th:href="@{/basket/decrease/{index}(index=${stat.index})}"
```

Please help me find where I have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of `-1`, `+1` use `--amount`, `++amount` to decrement and increment

```java
public void decreaseAmount(int basketItemIndex) {
    if (basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).getAmount() == 1)
        basketItems.remove(basketItemIndex);
    else {
        int amount = basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).getAmount();
        basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).setAmount(--amount);
    }
}

public void increaseAmount(int basketItemIndex) {
    int amount = basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).getAmount();
    basketItems.get(basketItemIndex).setAmount(++amount);
}
```

2. Change `@GetMapping("/decrease{basketItemIndex}")` to
   `@GetMapping("/decrease/{basketItemIndex}")` (add the slash after the `decrease`)